# How to access the data within object fetch from firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

How can i get access to the data from the object that i fetch from firebase forestore. I have code in which i get complete object from firebase like

```
localInvoice:{
  name:Ali, 
  date:29/09/2020,
  Phone:033562100555
 }
```

but when it comes to  access inner values of objects then i get error message. The error message is like, for example if i want to access the **name**

```
const[invoice, setInvoice]=useState({
  name:Ali, 
  date:29/09/2020,
  Phone:033562100555
 });
console.log(invoice.name);
//error message --> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

This is my [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-albattani-um1x5) in which

1. First I simply add data to my firestore
2. Secondly i am fetching the same data i added before. I am passing **name, phone, date, string date** as props to get the same data i added from firestore

if my question in not conveying properly then please ask me
it will be helpfull if changes should be done in code given in links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `currentInvoice` is an array, since you store it this way:

```
setCurrentInvoice(
   snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() }))
)
```

You can access the name like this:

```
console.log(currentInvoice[0].data.name);
```

However, if you only want to store the first invoice, you can do it so:

```
 setCurrentInvoice(snapshot.docs[0].data());
```

And then access the name like you wanted first:

```
console.log(invoice.name);
```

Comment: this code work for me but it work in <Unit /> compoent not in <LocalMidInvoice /> i want it to work on <LocalMidInvoice />

Comment: My code works actually in the LocalMidInvoice component

Comment: yes it works. and what if i also want the ID of the doc?

Comment: I just updated my ansewer, have a look at it ;)

Comment: I also get the ID Thanks @The Tisiboth

Answer (score 0):

When you request for data from firebase, it takes some times to fetch. within this time if you want to use data object. It will return 'undefined'.

To fix this you can use : `console.log(invoice && invoice.name);`

Comment: i still got undefined